# Strings overlap when fwrite is called from function

Tags: c, function, file, output, fwrite

my assignment was to display kernel information and now I have to output that to a log file. The program is long because it contains alot of parts so I will display the necessary ones. The main method is simply calling the part1()-part10() functions. My output is:

```
1. CPU tIntel(R)
```

When this is expected:

```
1. CPU type & model:     Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
```

part1():

```
int part1()
{
    char filename[] = "/proc/cpuinfo";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int n = 5; // Line on which information is contained. 
    int i;
    char line[256];

    if(fp != NULL)
    {    
        for(i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
        {
          fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
        }

        fclose(fp);

        printf("1. CPU type & model:\t %s", line+13);
        output("1. CPU type & model:\t", line+13);
        return 0;
    }
    else
      return 1;
}
```

output():

```
int output(char *x, char *y)
{
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen("local_kernel.log ", "a");

  fwrite(x , 1 , sizeof(x) , fp );
  fwrite(y , 1 , sizeof(y) , fp );

  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: You need [strlen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen), not "sizeof"!!!  "sizeof (char *)" is probably "4" (for a 32-bit system) ;)

Comment: Thanks! I get confused by those two too often -.-